# Handling Record List operations

Tags: sharepoint, office365, powerapps, o365-flow

I have a requirement where I need to maintain records of data in database table via SharePoint, provide powerapp or other solution based interface so that I could do the following+

1. Add, Update or Edit the Package records.
2. Pick desired records and create Parent to group them.

I heard that above mentioned grouping desired records ( building parent child ) relation is not supported in SharePoint either OOTB or Custom approach?

Request suggestion or direction that could be taken, if anyone has done something similiar.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly create parent-child relationships in sharepoint, what you can do is work around the IDs. Let's say you want to create a database of books... Every book has an author, and you want to store the data of the author as well.
You can create a table for authors, and a table for books. Each author you add to the list will have a name, surname, email, etc, and an unique **Author ID**.
Now you want to add a book for that author. In the book table you would give the book an **ID**, name, published date, etc, and instead of the name of the author, you would give it the **ID of the author** referencing the author data in the other table. If you want the author's name (for instance), all you need to do is search in the Author's table for that author ID.
This has been my workaround when doing parent-child tables in Sharepoint. Hope this makes sense to you. Best regards